# Реализация программы – генератор паролей на питоне

Tags: python

подскажите пожалуйста, как переделать код для реализации с такими заданными условиями? Где число 11 - это количество символов пароля

[image: Сам листинг кода]

[image: Условия]

Comment: Вставьте пожалуйста код текстом, а не картинкой

Comment: Я голосую за закрытие этого вопроса, потому что он был фактически удален автором

Comment: Пожалуйста, не редактируйте содержание вопроса после того как был дан и принят ответ. Это делает ответ бесполезным. И вставьте код текстом.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

В следующий раз, во-первых, кидайте код текстом, а не картинкой. Во-вторых, описывайте проблему понятнее, - здесь никто не хочет гадать, что именно вам необходимо. Уважайте комьюнити и оно будет уважать вас.

```
import random
import string


def get_password(identifier):    
    symbols_array = ['!', '"', "#", '$', '%', '&', "'", '(', ')', '*']
    q = identifier % 8
    password = ''
    
    for i in range(2):
        password += str(random.randint(0, 9))
    
    for i in range(q + 1):
        password += random.choice(string.ascii_uppercase)
    
    for i in range(11 - len(password)):
        password += random.choice(symbols_array)

    return password
```

Comment: Поставил бы плюс, если б в ответе был скриншот кода. :)

Comment: @sayfdor 
После ввода идентификатора программа выключается

Comment: @aepot, понимаю, но, как мне кажется, лучше просто сделать замечание, может быть, человек примет во внимание. Ну, а если нет, то второй его вопрос просто утопят в плохих оценках)

Comment: @AlterCore если вы запускаете код в терминале, то допишите в конце ```input()```, так, пока вы не введете что-то, программа не закроется.

Comment: @aepot, вообще думаю, а надо ли было отвечать автору вопроса, ибо мне минусов накидали. Если это за реализацию программы, - почему не написать, что не так, а если нет, то смысл ставить минусы.

Comment: Видите, автор просто удалил свой вопрос. Ваш ответ превратился в тыкву и стал бесполезен для StackOverflow. Конечно за такое участники ставят минусы. Автор плевал на правила базы знаний SO, а вы ему позволили это сделать. Я откатил правки, чтобы хоть что-то осталось

Comment: @aepot, хорошо, приму во внимание. Спасибо за конструктивную критику.